# OpenGL Spotlight shining through from rear-face

Tags: opengl

I have a Spotlight source in OpenGL, pointing towards a texture mapped sphere.

I rotate the lightsource with the sphere, such that if I rotate the sphere to the 'non-light' side, that side should be dark.

The odd part is, the spotlight seems to be shining through my sphere (it's a solid, no gaps between triangles.  The light seems to be 'leaking' through to the other side.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Screenshots:

[Front view, low light to emphasize the problem](http://www.logisticchaos.com/front.png)

[Back view, notice the round area that is 'shining through'](http://www.logisticchaos.com/back.png)

Comment: Can you post the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Its really hard to tell from the images, but:

Check if GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE is being set (two sided lighting), but more importantly have a look at the normals of the sphere you are rendering.

Edit: Also - change the background colour to something lighter. Oh and make sure you aren't rendering with alpha blending turned on (maybe its a polygon sorting issue).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm a nob - I was specifying my normals, but not calling glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY).  Hence all normals were facing one direction (I think that's the default, no?)

Anyway - a lesson learned - always go back over the basics.